# Hide the in-function plot from R package

Tags: r, plot, package, hide, in-function

I am using the R package "GeoDE". When I use the function "chdirAnalysis", a figure will be plotted automatically, since there is a command "plot" in the source code of "chdirAnalysis". But I don't want that. How can I stop this?

A similar problem is to hide the in-function printed messages, and I've found the solution which is to use invisible

```
capture.output(value <- function_name(input))
```

That can help hide the output from "function_name", but this solution doesn't work on the plot.

Answer (score 2):

Options:

1. Ask the maintainer to add a `plot=FALSE` option to the function (and maybe a `verbose=FALSE` option to stop the text outputs).
2. Edit the source for `chdirAnalysis` and remove the function call that does the plotting, or hide it behind a new `plot=FALSE` options. I think this is `chdirplots`, which is called but doesn't do anything with its return value. If you are doing this outside the GeoDE package source then you'll need to add the `GeoDE:::` prefix to any unexported `GeoDE` functions called by `chdirAnalysis` (such as `chdirSig`).
3. Make it plot to some dummy or throwaway graphics device file, as described in other questions and answers.

Comment: Thank you @Spacedman. I'll do that as "1". For 2, that's very helpful. Since I tried to paste the definition of `chdirAnalysis` in my code, and modified it by removing the plot part, but as it will call another function in the package `chdirSig`, I had to paste that function's definition to my code. But `GeoDE:::` solves this problem perfectly! For 3, sorry, but I don't understand.

Comment: (3) Is doing something like `pdf(file="/dev/null")` which opens a graphics device that sends its output to a PDF file which (on Linux/Unix) just goes nowhere. You could even send it to a real file, like `t = tempfile();pdf(file=t); doplotstuff(...); dev.off();file.remove(t)` and that won't do it on screen.

Comment: Learnt something new. Thx!